# How to load previous kernel via ssh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, ssh, grub, kernel

I work remotely on my work computer. I am also the root of the workstation that I am sharing with my colleague. Yesterday, I upgraded the kernel to 2.6.31-17 when asked by the update manager but refrained from restarting because I knew my NVIDIA and several other kernel modules wouldn't work. Unfortunately my colleague who is a linux noob restarted the machine and here I am :(

I am thinking of changing the symlinks /initrd.img and /vmlinuz to the previous kernel image and use kexec. Please tell some better way to load the 2.6.31-16 release of kernel from ssh and not the grub boot menu. I am using Ubuntu Karmic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't select it from SSH.

You could use SSH to

- a) check the Grub settings to make sure your previous kernel is still an option in the Grub menu,
- b) set Grub to automatically boot to that option,
- c) and finally reboot the system.

This is very similar to a boot-once solution -- I wrote up [instructions with Grub v1](https://serverfault.com/questions/92890/linux-command-line-partition-reboot-selection/92916#92916) in this answer on ServerFault.

If you're using Grub2, you'll have to do some investigating to find the right configuration -- apparently the `grub-set-default` command doesn't work in Karmic.  See ["Grub 2 - 5 Common Tasks"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1302743) on UbuntuForums -- #2 deals with modifying the default entry; option 3 in that talks about modifying that through the Grub2 configuration files:

> You can see the current "menuentry" items listed in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
>   by running this command:
>
> ```
> grep "menuentry" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```
>
> Counting starts with zero (0). The first "menuentry" item is "0", the
>   second is "1", etc. The third visible "menuentry" would be 2.
>
> Determine the number you wish to make the default, and enter it
>   in /etc/default/grub. Make the change and save the file.
>
> ```
>  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> The user can also select "saved" as an option, which will use the
>   last successfully booted kernel/OS as the default selection.
>
> ```
>  # Example: 
>  DEFAULT="saved"
> ```
>
> Save the file, then update the menu:
>
> ```
>  sudo update-grub
> ```

You'll need to locate the entry for your older kernel.  Once you've changed the default entry to your older kernel and updated Grub, you should be able to reboot the system (`sudo reboot now`) -- after waiting for it to come back up, you should be running the old kernel.

Comment: Odd question, great answer.  How can you select anything from ssh?

Answer (score 1):

I found out there is also a GUI editor for Grub2 in universe repository called [startupmanager](https://launchpad.net/startup-manager). I used it actually.

Comment: It was/is for GRUB1, too. Just has less features at the moment on GRUB2.

Comment: this was mentioned in the UbuntuForums post i linked to, but i described the commandline alternative since you asked about SSH.  still, obviously X forwarding via SSH makes this a good solution too.